# Web scraping WebDriverException Traceback (most recent call last)

Tags: python, selenium-webdriver

```py
from bs4 import BeautifulSoupgives 
from selenium import webdriver
import requests
import statistics

from selenium import webdriver
from webdriver_manager.chrome import ChromeDriverManager

options = webdriver.ChromeOptions()
options.binary_location = r"C:\Program Files\Google\Chrome\Application\chrome.exe"
chrome_driver_binary = r"C:\Users\Константин\Downloads\chromedriver_win32\chromedriver.exe"
driver = webdriver.Chrome(chrome_driver_binary, chrome_options=options)
driver.get('https://russiabasket.ru/teams/718?apiUrl=https://asb.infobasket.su&compId=45595&lang=ru')
```

Answer (score 0):

Since you didn't specify a problem I just ran your code, this is a mistake I found.

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoupgives
```

Should be

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
```

Must have been a typo, hope this helps and actually is your problem!